# TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When trying to visit a page within my Rails app I am now receiving

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
```

Here is the full stack trace. It looks to me like something w/ the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. Am I correct?

```
TypeError (can't convert Symbol into String):
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.4) lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb:20:in `eval'
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.4) lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb:20:in `add_breadcrumb'
  twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.4) lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb:11:in `block in add_breadcrumb'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__1576526312124645203__process_action__39584884573935751__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__400543747363831273__call__3603336714283860524__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.2) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/Kyle/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of `lib/twitter/bootstrap/rails/twitter-bootstrap-breadcrumbs.rb`

Comment: As the error occures in `eval`, could you post the code working with the plugin in the controller? I guess that you have somewhere some arguments wrong. If you are using an symbol, try converting it to a sting with the `to_s` method.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are you aren't using the version of ruby you think you are using.  Did you just update ruby?

If you are using rbenv or rvm try switching which version you are using and see if the error persists.  Maybe you're using jruby?

Could you post the results of the following commands on this thread?

```
which ruby
ruby --version
```